# Parse files, hidden from the user

Tags: neovim, snippets, lsp, plugin-treesitter

I am working on a snippet for C/C++ that can generate switch statements with cases from the types that an enum can have.
So far I have some code that can get the type location from the language server. The process I have in mind is:

1. Get type location with LSP
2. Open file with type definition in some hidden buffer (I am not sure how to do this)
3. Parse the hidden buffer using treesitter to get list of enum values
4. Use list to generate cases for the switch statement

I really have no idea of how to do step 2, the LSP result is a location in a file, and I have some code to create an empty buffer, but I cannot find any thing about doing this, I wound imagine this being a normal use case for plugins, to have some kind of hidden working area to parse files or similar.

Comment: You can probably get the file content with `readfile()` or similar; then, if you can get treesitter to run on that content, you're probably most of the way there.

Comment: I have used `vim.api.nvim_buf_call` to call view on the file in a buffer created for this,I think that is going to work..
I will do a longer post when I make it all work